# Unabled to build the app on adding react native admob

Tags: admob, build.gradle, react-native

I am working on an existing app, which is having older dependencies.
This is my **app/build.gradle**

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+'
```

Now I want to add google adds, hence I followed - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob

But after the installation I was not able to sync the app. So I updated the dependencies to the recent versions.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0" 
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+'
```

Even after that I am getting the error as

```
Gradle sync failed: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

Please let me know what needs to be fixed.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The library `react-native-admob` has a dependency declared as '+' for the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` in it's `build.gradle`. This will fetch the latest version of the library from maven repo.

Also I see you have used the `applovin-sdk`, which also is dependent on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads`.

This is clashing with your version declaration in your `android/app/build.gradle` file, which is `16.1.0`.

Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` in your RN projects `android` folder. This will  show you the dependency tree.
Find out which library is using the older play-service dependency and force it to use the latest version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api`.

Check out this article for forcing the versions: https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

But I have managed the ads using firebase. :)

Comment: No argument there, but that library's `play-service` dependencies are clashing with your declaration so check it out

Comment: AppLovin's SDK only needs Play Services Identity, so I'd add `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0"` only for AppLovin.